# how to create web server control using asp.net that contain RequiredFieldValidator control that validate textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to web server control using asp.net that contain TextBox with RequiredFieldValidator controls. i have tried but validation control not work.

please help me thanks in advance.

```
    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        Panel mypanel = new Panel();
        TextBox txtName = new TextBox();
        txtName.ID = "txtNameVal";
        txtName.EnableViewState = true;

        RequiredFieldValidator myrqv = new RequiredFieldValidator();
        myrqv.ErrorMessage = "Please enter the value";
        myrqv.EnableViewState = true;
        myrqv.EnableTheming = true;
        myrqv.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Inherit;
        myrqv.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
        myrqv.ValidateRequestMode = System.Web.UI.ValidateRequestMode.Inherit;
        myrqv.ViewStateMode = System.Web.UI.ViewStateMode.Inherit;

        myrqv.ControlToValidate = txtName.ID;
        //myrqv.Text = "*";
        txtName.AutoPostBack = false;
        mypanel.Controls.Add(txtName);
        mypanel.Controls.Add(myrqv);


        mypanel.RenderControl(output);

        output.Write("<br/><br/>");
        string mytxt = "<br/>";
        output.Write(mytxt);
        //output.Write(Text);
    }
```

vilas jadhav

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solution:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2748/Building-an-ASP-NET-custom-web-control-a-textbox-a